# How to execute multiple test fragments in a single thread group through commandline

Tags: jmeter, test-script

I have a test plan in which i am using 5 Test Fragments given below and using a single Thread Group
Test Fragment A
Test Fragment B
Test Fragment C
Test Fragment D
Test Fragment E

If i use 5 Module controllers i.e one for each test fragment , my test would run for all 5 test fragments.
Is there any functionality which helps me to specify which Fragment i want to execute through command line.
For eg: For Test 1 I want to execute only TF A & TF B and For Test 2 i need TF C, TF D & TF E.
How can i achieve this through any controller in the script or commandline.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you're looking for the [Weighted Switch Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-weighted-switch-controller-the-ultimate-guide), put all your Module Controllers under it and you will be able to distribute the load by providing "weight" for the children by their name.

For example

- if you don't want to execute specific module controller - set its weight to 0
- if you want to execute only one controller - set its weight to 100 and others to 0
- if you want to execute 2 controllers - set their weights to 50 or 100 and increase the number of threads/loops accordingly

You can parameterize the weights and the number of threads loops by:

- passing the values using [-J command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)
- and reading the values using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P)